# Custom ShowcaseView

Tags: android, showcaseview

I am familiar implementing ShowCaseView as helper/walkthrough, and it's working really great. Now I want to know If I can customized the showcaseview layout like adding a button on the left side of default 'OK' button. And also I want to add a 'skip all' button in case user don't want to view all showcaseviews.

Is that possible? If so, can anyone point me how? Thanks in advance. Have a nice day!

Comment: See if [this](https://github.com/JesusM/ShowcaseViewLibrary) helps., and [this, too](http://novoda.com/blog/Using-the-ShowcaseView)

Answer (score 0):

I extended ShowcaseView and added the ability to add multiple buttons and customize them as needed. The code is here: https://github.com/vabh/ShowcaseView

So, you can add the extra buttons and position them as you want.

Comment: 404 on repo link. Downvoting.

Comment: I could find the link. Seems like it was updated later. https://github.com/vabh/ShowcaseViewExtended